# Resolve and bind to IPv6 address

Tags: c, bind, ipv6, getaddrinfo

I wrote a program that resolves an address or hostname and then attempts to bind to that address in `listen(2)` mode. For some strange reason I am unable to use IPv6 addresses, the program simply fails with "Invalid argument" after calling `bind(2)`. With IPv4 everything works as I would expect it to work, names get resolved, and addresses are simply converted to binary format.

**Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int
resolve_addr (const char *hostname, const char *service, int family, struct addrinfo **result)
{
    struct addrinfo addr_hint;

    memset (&addr_hint, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));

    addr_hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    addr_hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV | AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    addr_hint.ai_family = family;

    return getaddrinfo (hostname, service, &addr_hint, result);
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo *addr;
    int rval, sock, opt_val;

    rval = resolve_addr (argv[1], argv[2], AF_UNSPEC, &addr);

    if ( rval != 0 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", gai_strerror (rval));
        return 1;
    }

    sock = socket (addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype | SOCK_NONBLOCK, addr->ai_protocol);

    if ( sock == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error socket: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if ( setsockopt (sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof (opt_val)) == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error setsockopt: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if ( bind (sock, (struct sockaddr*) addr->ai_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error bind: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if ( listen (sock, 32) == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error listen: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    sleep (120);

    freeaddrinfo (addr);
    close (sock);

    return 0;
}
```

**Usage**

1. `./test_bind localhost 8888 # works`
2. `./test_bind 0.0.0.0 8888 # works`
3. `./test_bind 127.0.0.1 8888 # works`
4. `./test_bind :: 8888 # does not work: Invalid argument`
5. `./test_bind ::1 8888 # does not work: Invalid argument`

**Side note**

I used the netcat to find out if there's something wrong with my system but the following command works:

`ncat -l :: 8888`

as can be seen in netstat:

`tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN`

Comment: You can open netstat source code. :)

Comment: Different `sockaddr_*` structures are different sizes; use `addr->ai_addrlen` instead of `sizeof(sockaddr)`.

Comment: @dave_thompson Thank you, I arrived to the same conclusion. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I updated my code and both IPv4 and IPv6 are resolved and binded to successfully.The problem was in the third paramater of `bind(2)` function which was calculating the size of an address from the structure size, instead of using a value from the `getaddrinfo` result.

I replaced the line:

`if ( bind (sock, (struct sockaddr*) addr->ai_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1 ){`

with:

`if ( bind (sock, (struct sockaddr*) addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == -1 ){`

**Full source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int
resolve_addr (const char *hostname, const char *service, int family, struct addrinfo **result)
{
    struct addrinfo addr_hint;

    memset (&addr_hint, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));

    addr_hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    addr_hint.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV | AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    addr_hint.ai_family = family;

    return getaddrinfo (hostname, service, &addr_hint, result);
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo *addr;
    int rval, sock, opt_val;

    rval = resolve_addr (argv[1], argv[2], AF_UNSPEC, &addr);

    if ( rval != 0 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", gai_strerror (rval));
        return 1;
    }

    sock = socket (addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype | SOCK_NONBLOCK, addr->ai_protocol);

    if ( sock == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error socket: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    opt_val = 1;

    if ( setsockopt (sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof (opt_val)) == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error setsockopt: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if ( bind (sock, (struct sockaddr*) addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error bind: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if ( listen (sock, 32) == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr, "error listen: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        return 1;
    }

    sleep (120);

    freeaddrinfo (addr);
    close (sock);

    return 0;
}
```